# Language in the Jinx fantasy series

Tags: object-identification

In the *Jinx* series by Sage Blackwood, there is a language where to speak a sentence, you open the first word in half, insert the second and split in half. Repeat till your sentence is finished. I believe the name of the language starts with Q.

Disclaimer: I know the tag isn’t the correct one, but I couldn’t find a better one.

Comment: Object-ID is a perfectly fine tag for this. You've already identified the story, so it's not a Story-ID question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean "***Qunthk***", I assume? Unless there's another Q-named language in the series?

This was very hard to find and took me until the last page of a Google search of "*Jinx "Sage Blackwood" language*" to even find the name.

The quote you're referring to is from the second book in the series:

> Why do you have books in Qunthk? Can you actually read them?”
>
> “Not exactly,” said Jinx. “Can you?”
>
> “No. It’s famously impossible to learn, because the words are all stuck inside each other. What are all these pictures of bottles?”
>
> “What do you mean, ‘stuck inside each other’?” said Jinx.
>
> **“That’s how you make a sentence in Qunthk. Instead of stringing the words one after another, you split the first word and put the second inside it, and split that and put the third inside, and split that—”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Jinx's Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/18085456-jinx-s-magic)</sup></sub>

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in a better quote. I'm 99% certain this is what OP is referring to